# fancy upload, file meta info problem

Tags: file-upload, fancyupload

I'm uploading files using [fancy upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/). Back end is in Java Servlet. How to retrieve file meta info, such as: name and mimeType. Servlet Request parameters are empty. How can it be achieved? How to pass parameters?